# AtomicInteger conditional check thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, atomicinteger

I ran across a doubt if below is thread safe,

```
// is this thread safe, final int MAX_COUNT = 3 ?
if (retryCount.get() < MAX_COUNT) {
    // some other code
    retryCount.getAndIncrement();
} else {
    // reset count & some other code
    retryCount.set(0);
}
```

Is the above conditional check thread safe ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it doesn't.

Suppose two threads `T1` and `T2` and `retryCount` contains actually the `2` value.
Suppose `T1` executes `if(retryCount.get() < MAX_COUNT){` (evaluated to true) but doesn't reach `retryCount.getAndIncrement();`.
`T1` is paused. `T2` is resumed.
`T2` executes `if(retryCount.get() < MAX_COUNT){` that is still evaluated to true.

So you are sure that `retryCount` will be valued to `4`.

You need explicit synchronization and in this case the `AtomicInteger` **may** not be required :

```
synchronized(lock){
  if(retryCount.get() < MAX_COUNT){
  // some other code
  retryCount.getAndIncrement();
  }else{
   // reset count & some other code
   retryCount.set(0);
  } 
}
```

Comment: Alternatively could use `retryCount.getAndUpdate(i -> (i + 1) % (MAX_COUNT + 1))`.

Comment: @Bubletan you're leaving out the 'other code' portion.

Comment: @matt Well I did assume the other code can be executed in any order.

Comment: @Bubletan’s example can be extended to `if(retryCount.updateAndGet(i -> (i + 1) % (MAX_COUNT + 1)) != 0) { /* code for ordinary case */ } else { /* code when resetting */ }` if that’s not suitable, i.e. the order of the “other code” and the counter update matters, then `AtomicInteger` is not the right tool for the job. As then, all other access to the `retryCount` and to whatever “other code” modifies needs synchronization (*on the same lock*) too…

Answer (score 1):

No it's not thread safe because the code is performing what's called a [`check-then-act`](http://brevitaz.com/race-condition-java-concurrency-2/) operation.

`AtomicInteger` is thread safe in itself meaning it's individual methods are atomic but performing compound operations are not atomic. so the above code needs synchronization

here's some great notes from **[Java Concurrency In Practice](https://gist.github.com/jasonkeene/b83162c0e41d4befc0b9a03d10a760a3)**